# yum install mysql-devel.x86_64 error Centos5

Tags: mysql, centos, centos5, libselinux

I use yum install mysql-devel.x86_64 on centos5, but error like this:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  package libselinux-1.33.4-5.7.el5.centos.x86_64 (which is newer than libselinux-1.33.4-5.7.el5.i386) is already installed

Error Summary
-------------
```

rpm libselinux:

```
[root@23375c2631b1 rcserver]# rpm -qa |grep libselinux
libselinux-1.33.4-5.7.el5.centos
libselinux-utils-1.33.4-5.7.el5.centos
```

**How to fix that?**

Comment: It's already been installed, why not just use it?

Comment: Maybe x86_64 different i386？Because dependenciy libselinux-i386

Answer (score 4):

Downgrading libselinux worked for me.

```
yum downgrade libselinux
```